# Input field span element goes out of it

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-4

I'm having problem with formatting span element in input field. Element goes completely out of line. It is position in top right corner. I'm working with Angular 2.

Here is HTML:

```
<div class="form-section">
  <div class="form-group">
 <div class="form-group">
    <label for="flowRate">Flow Rate</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="number" step="any" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="tmpFlowRate" id="flowRate" (input)="emitChange()" onfocus="this.select();">
    <span class="inline-label">{{settings.flowMeasurement}}</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

And my CSS file:

```
.inline-label {
  white-space: nowrap;
  max-width: 190px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Comment: You're not applying your CSS to the `span`; you're applying it to the `input`.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Sorry forgot to change. I will like my units to display inside input field in the right side not the outside.